# Pivot or Case Statement?

Tags: db2, pivot, recursive-query

I'm looking to pivot my data on location_id having multiple rows instead of one. I have multiple locations and I need an easier way to pivot my data and calculate several totals without having to hard code the location_name every time.  Was not sure how to approach this and would appreciate a push in the right direction.  DB2 database.

```
SELECT RowNumber () over (PARTITION BY DIM_LOCATION_ID ORDER BY LOCATION_NAME),

        DIM_LOCATION_ID,
        LOCATION_NAME,

        (
        SELECT 
        SUM(SALES_AMOUNT) AS SALES_SUMMARY
        FROM FACT_TABLE
        WHERE LOCATION_NAME = 'DENVER'

        ) AS SALES_SUMMARYDV,

        (
        SELECT 
        SUM(SALES_AMOUNT) AS SALES_SUMMARY
        FROM FACT_TABLE
        WHERE LOCATION_NAME = 'CHICAGO'

        ) AS SALES_SUMMARYCH,

            (
        SELECT
        SUM(ORDERS) AS SUMMARY_ORDERS
        FROM FACT_TABLE
        WHERE LOCATION_NAME = 'DENVER'

        ) AS ORDER_SUMMARYDV,


        (
        SELECT
        SUM(ORDERS) AS SUMMARY_ORDERS
        FROM FACT_TABLE
        WHERE LOCATION_NAME = 'CHICAGO'

        ) AS ORDER_SUMMARYCH



    FROM FACT_TABLE 
    GROUP BY DIM_LOCATION_ID, LOCATION_NAME  
    ORDER BY LOCATION_NAME
```

DESIRED RESULTS:
[image]

Comment: You really need to provide your table definitions and sample data. Just providing code alone isn't enough.

Comment: Which DB2 platform are you using? DB2 for i, z/OS, LUW (Linux, Unix,Windows)? And which version?

Comment: It isn't clear from your question, why a regular GROUP BY would not give you the desired output. i.e.,   select DIM_LOCATION_ID, LOCATION_NAME, sum(SALES_AMOUNT), sum(ORDERS) from FACT_TABLE group by DIM_LOCATION_ID, LOCATION_NAME

Comment: I believe that a rollup clause will help me reach a solution.  I'm creating a summary view with multiple aggregations that have different filters.  I was looking for a more efficient way to do this without having several subqueries.